# Button with onClick only works once in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I need to make a collapse menu in a React app, but the button with onClick only works once. I created a boolean variable and it should change when I tap the button. But I can tap the button only once and thereafter the `<a>` doesn't work, it's inactive:

```
let isOpened = false;

class Header extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    isOpened = !isOpened;
  };

  render() {
    const path = history.location && history.location.pathname;
    return (
      <div className={s['header-left']}>
        <div className={s.button}>
          <a href="#"  onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
          </a>
        </div>
```

And the collapse code:

```
<Collapse isOpened={isOpened}>
        <nav className={`${s.menu} ${s.mobile}`}>
          <ul className={s['menu-ul']}>
            ...
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </Collapse>
```

Comment: The `render` function in the code snippet `Header` class - and the whole class - is incomplete. I guess you omitted the end of it by accident (?).

Comment: @ProgrammerPer In my code render function complete. I put away some parts that code would be compactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your onClick is working fine but it is not re-rendering your react component. You need to put `isOpened` in the state of the component and global variable. Please read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {isOpened: false};
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({isOpened: !this.state.isOpened});
  };

  render() {
    const path = history.location && history.location.pathname;
    return (
      <div className={s['header-left']}>
        <div className={s.button}>
          <a href="#"  onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
          </a>
        </div>
   );
 }
```

Comment: I have an error
ReferenceError: isOpened is not defined
Header/<
C:/Users/Ð Ð¾Ð¼Ð°Ð½/WebstormProjects/pbh_web-master/src/components/Header/Header.js:20

  17 |   this.state = {isOpened: false};
  18 | }
  19 | handleClick = () => {
> 20 |   this.setState({isOpened: !isOpened});
     | ^  21 | };
  22 | 
  23 | render() {

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Hm, after all fixes button work only once time, when I'm on start page, cursor highlights my button as a link (it's work). But when I tab on button, it stand unactive, cursor highlights button as text or picture and when I trying to tab on it, nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Addendum to answer of @Ajay Gaur

Your problem is in the using `<a href="#"  onClick={this.handleClick}>`
When you try to click on a link browser want to redirect you to the next page becouse in `a` you added `href="#"`.
So there are two ways to solve your problem.

1: Use `button` instead `a` tag.

2: Add preventDefaul to your method:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ isOpened: !this.state.isOpened });
};
```

It should to help.

Comment: I solve the problem. The previous answer was right. It will be problems wuth markup, the menu was over button