# Transparent iFrame blocks mouse event when using react-scripts start

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Has anyone ever come across this issue?

When using `react-scripts start`, everything seems ok on first load. As soon as a change is made to a file, all the mouse event seem to stop working (can't click on buttons, inputs, no tooltips etc.), even though the browser appears to update.

If I refresh the page the events work again, until a file is changed.

This isn't a problem in production as the watcher isn't involved there.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:
I've found the problem but I'm not sure what the solution is.
It appears that a iFrame is added to the DOM when the watcher reloads. It looks like it has something to do with licenses. The body within the iFrame is empty but there is some minified JS with a comment on the top line:

> /*! For license information please see iframe-bundle.js.LICENSE.txt */

Does anyone know how to prevent this iFrame appearing.

Comment: can you put click event code with question

Comment: I wouldn't be posting anything different to the react examples here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html
The issue is likely environmental, I don't think specific code would be useful here

Comment: this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465983/button-with-onclick-only-works-once-in-react

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that isn't the same problem. I'll update the question to add more detail

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is what fixed it for me:

```
npm upgrade react-scripts
```

Comment: Spot on :) I was using v4.* with react v17.*. Upgrade to v5 worked. Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me nuts.

Comment: Glad it wasn't just me. It's very frustrating! Anyone have any idea how this ended up in there? Unfortunatley running 5.0.0 gives me myriad other errors such as "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\..."

Comment: So what do we do if v5 breaks because webpack 5 doesn't include polyfills anymore?

Comment: @MoritzRoessler See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71331978/3499115

Comment: I was revisitng a very, very old project and experienced this. Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem but I do not have `react-scripts` installed

Answer (score 10):

This works for me:

```
"react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
```

and **add** the fixed dependency version to the resolutions section of your **package.json**:

```
"resolutions": {
  "//": "See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773",
  "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
},
```

**Notice:** please put this dependency into `"resolutions":{ }` of **package.json**. It won't work in "devDependencies" or "dependencies" .

Comment: it works for me when I put `react-error-overlay` in both **devDependencies** and **resolutions**

Answer (score 3):

You need to upgrade React-Scripts to latest version

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to react-scripts v5 that way made it work for me :

```sh
npm i react-scripts@5.0.0
```

Comment: This one helped me too.

Answer (score 1):

My solution npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@5.0.0   then rm -rf node_module && rm -rf package-lock.json   y then npm install and npm start =)