# React-app renders an Iframe and it causes bug, How to delete it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

In the app, an Iframe is rendered in HTML and it gets some ridiciolus z-index value and covers whole the page. This makes my other components completely unreachable, unclickable. I just started working on this existing app so don't know where this iframe might be coming from.
[image]

I have searched for the iframe and its style values in folders but found nothing actually.
This image shows script tag inside body may be includes something worth a look.
[image]
I have reduced the width and height and changed the bg-color of iframe to make it visible

So, If you have an idea, please share with me. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70721056/transparent-iframe-blocks-mouse-event-when-using-react-scripts-start

Comment: Thank you, updating the react-scripts solved the problem but also caused another problem in webpack config. Different error message means progress :)